# Getting the useful words from a word list

Tags: php, string-matching

I have the following strings:

```
Over/Under 1.5
Over/Under 2.5
Over/Under 3.5
Over/Under 4.5
This is not Over/Under 1.5
Other text
```

For me the valid texts are the following

```
Over/Under 1.5
Over/Under 2.5
Over/Under 3.5
Over/Under 4.5
Over/Under X.X
```

where the `X.X` is a number.

How can I make a decision weather is a valid string or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `This es not Over/Under 1.5` match?  If so:

```
$words = array('Over/Under 1.5',
'Over/Under 2.5',
'Over/Under 3.5',
'Over/Under 4.5',
'This es not Over/Under 1.5',
'Other text');

foreach ($words as $word) {
  if (preg_match('#.*Over/Under \d\.\d.*#', $word)) {
    echo "Match $word\n";
  }
}
```

If not, change the preg_match to

```
preg_match('#^Over/Under \d\.\d$#', $word);
```

Like @Tokk writes, if the string should match on Over OR Under, then you need to change to an OR - |

```
preg_match('#^(Over|Under) \d\.\d$#', $word);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('/Over\/Under \d\.\d/', $str)) {

}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I want to get false for this string 'Half-time Totals Over/Under 0.5', but I'm getting true.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it matches the Regex

```
Over/Under [0-9]*.[0-9]*
```

(if it is Over OR Under, choose `(Over|Under)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression. I'm not very good at them myself, but this worked for me:

$t

```
mp  = array
(
    "Over/Under 1.5",
    "Over/Under 2.5",
    "Over/Under 3.5",
    "Over/Under 4.5",
    "Over/Under 5.5",
    "fdgdfgdf",
    "Other"
);

$tmp2 = array_filter($tmp, function($element) { return preg_match('(Over\/Under [0-9]\.[0-9])', $element); });
print_r($tmp2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for more info